# Evaluating the trigonometric integral $\int\frac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x} \,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

> $$\int\frac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x} \,dx$$

How do I go about tackling this problem? I tried doing integration by parts but that didn't work, I tried using substitution but that didn't work either so I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The "standard substitution" (usually the first thing to try) is $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$. That takes you to $\int\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\ dt$. Write the integrand as $-1+\frac{2}{1+t^2}$ and the rest is obvious.

Comment: @almagest ... I would say that $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ not "the first thing to try" since it will usually be longer than any other method which is applicable.  But if no other method works, then you have to try it.

Comment: @GEdgar Well these things are a matter of taste. The snag about hunting around for elegant solutions is that it can end up taking much longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint $\cos(x)=\frac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$ so the integral reduces to $0.5\int (1-\tan^2(x/2))dx$ where we can then use identity $\tan^2(x/2)=\sec^2(x/2)-1$ to get the final integral which is $x-\tan(x/2)+C$

Comment: I was thinking about this approach too! According to Mathematica the answer should be $x-\tan(x/2)$ though, but I don't yet see how you made a wrong step.

Comment: Sorry I ignored $0.5$ let me edit

Comment: See derivative of $tan(x/2)$ is $sec^2(x/2).0.5$ so this 0.5 and above one cancels giving the answer

Comment: Now the answer is the same as Mathematica's, but I don't see how $0.5\int 1- \tan^2(...) = 0.5\int 1- (\tan^2(...)-1)$ becomes $2x$.

Comment: Oh you're right! My bad :P

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Here's one method: Rewrite the integrand as $$\frac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \cos x},$$ so that the integral becomes $$\int \frac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x} \,dx= \int \left(1 - \frac{1}{1 + \cos x}\right) dx = x - {\int \frac{dx}{1 + \cos x}} .$$ Now, the remaining integral can be handled by exploiting the Pythagorean identity: $$\frac{1}{1 + \cos x} = \frac{1}{1 + \cos x} \cdot \frac{1 - \cos x}{1 - \cos x} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{1 - \cos^2 x} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{\sin^2 x} .$$

> **Additional hint** Now, $${\int \frac{1 - \cos x}{\sin^2 x} dx} = \int \frac{dx}{\sin^2 x} - \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x} \,dx .$$ The first integral is elementary, and the second can be handled with a straightforward substitution.

Comment: the second one is elementary too. $$\int - \cot x \csc x dx = \csc x  + C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{\cos \left(x\right)}{1+\cos \left(x\right)}dx$$
Apply integral substitution: $\color{green}{u=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\quad \:dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du}$
$$\int \frac{\cos \left(x\right)}{1+\cos \left(x\right)}dx\color{red}{=\int \frac{2}{u^2+1}du-\int \:1du}$$
Now it's easy...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-1}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{\cos x dx}{1+\cos x}=\int \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$
$$=x-\tan\frac{x}{2}+\mathbb C$$